# Edge between all nodes in NetworkX Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I am able to add an edge between any two individual node like below:

`G.add_edge(node1, node)`

But if I wanted to and edge between any two nodes (All nodes should be adjacent to each other) it becomes difficult when large number of nodes are taken.

**Example:**
If number are nodes are four and they are 1,2,3,4.The Graph should look like this
[image]

For above graph I am adding nodes as follow:

```
graph = [(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4), (2, 3),(2, 4), (3, 4)]
for edge in graph:
        G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
```

Is there any default option as parameter in Graph construction for my requirement?

Basically I need to construct a clique for given nodes.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description I think you're trying to make a complete graph.  Networkx has a built in method to create a complete graph.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.complete_graph(4)
G.edges()
>[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

If you don't want the nodes to be named `0,1,2,3`, then you can rename the nodes in `G` with some other names.  Follow the commands above with:

```
nodenames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
mapping = {i:nodename for i,nodename in enumerate(nodenames)}
#now mapping looks like {0:'a', 1:'b', ...}
H=nx.relabel_nodes(G,mapping)
H.edges()
> [('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'd'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('b', 'd')]
```

(note - I'm not a fan of the dict comprehension I used to define `mapping` - I'd appreciate if anyone can give me a more direct version that doesn't require enumerating).

Comment: Yeah it resolved my problem thank u Joel , It would be useful if we can pass Nodes as parameter instead of relabelling them.

Comment: @djkpA refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52498330/3552975)

Comment: "I'd appreciate if anyone can give me a more direct version that doesn't require enumerating". Still with enumerate(), but without the comprehension: `dict(enumerate(nodenames))`.